# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() inside AsyncTask for ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, progressdialog, looper

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I'm using AsyncTask to run some processes in the background.

I have:

```
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
    connectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SetPreference.this);
    connectionProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    connectionProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    connectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to site...");
    connectionProgressDialog.show();

    downloadSpinnerProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SetPreference.this);
    downloadSpinnerProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    downloadSpinnerProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading wallpaper...");
}
```

When I get into `doInBackground()` depending on a condition I:

```
[...]    
connectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
downloadSpinnerProgressDialog.show();
[...]
```

Whenever I try `downloadSpinnerProgressDialog.show()` I receive the error.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The method `show()` must be called from the [User-Interface (UI) thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653478/443982), while `doInBackground()` runs on different thread which is the main reason why `AsyncTask` was designed.

You have to call `show()` either in `onProgressUpdate()` or in `onPostExecute()`.

For example:

```
class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // Your onPreExecute method.

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Your code.
        if (condition_is_true) {
            this.publishProgress("Show the dialog");
        }
        return "Result";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        connectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
        downloadSpinnerProgressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick for me, just tried "AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);" and added the configuration of the builder. Trying to show this inside the onProgressUpdate leads to exactly the same error. Any ideas ?

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, I didn't realise you could override onProgressUpdate with any variable type using publishProgress(). Really helped me, to simply update with toast messages.

Answer (score 81):

I had a similar issue but from reading this question I figured I could run on UI thread:

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Seems to do the trick for me.

Comment: getActivity().runOnUiThread(this::mymethod);                                                               Thanks worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time making this work too, the solution for me was to use both hyui and konstantin answers,

```
class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

// Your onPreExecute method.

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Your code.
    if (condition_is_true) {
        this.publishProgress("Show the dialog");
    }
    return "Result";
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           alertDialog.show();
       }
     });
 }

}
```

Comment: I thought stuff done in `onProgressUpdate()` was automatically going to run on the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msgs) {
        //write your code hear which give error
        }
        }

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        //this will call handleMessage function and hendal all error
    }
    }).start();
```