# What is the Android UiThread (UI thread)

Tags: android, ui-thread

Can someone explain to me what exactly the UI thread is?
On developer.android.com it says about the runOnUiThread function

> public final void runOnUiThread (Runnable action)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the
>   current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed
>   immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is
>   posted to the event queue of the UI thread.

Does the UI thread mean that this will be run everytime the activity is pushed the the background by some ui activity like incoming call or screen dimming etc.? If not, what exactly does the UI thread include ?

Thank you

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The UIThread is the main thread of execution for your application. This is where most of your application code is run. All of your application components (Activities, Services, ContentProviders, BroadcastReceivers) are created in this thread, and any system calls to those components are performed in this thread.

For instance, let's say your application is a single Activity class. Then all of the lifecycle methods and most of your event handling code is run in this UIThread. These are methods like `onCreate`, `onPause`, `onDestroy`, `onClick`, etc. Additionally, this is where all of the updates to the UI are made. Anything that causes the UI to be updated or changed HAS to happen on the UI thread.

[For more info on your application's Processes and Threads click here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

When you explicitly spawn a new thread to do work in the background, this code is not run on the UIThread. So what happens if this background thread needs to do something that changes the UI? This is what the `runOnUiThread` is for. Actually you're supposed to use a Handler (see the link below for more info on this). It provides these background threads the ability to execute code that can modify the UI. They do this by putting the UI-modifying code in a Runnable object and passing it to the runOnUiThread method.

[For more info on spawning worker threads and updating the UI from them click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads)

I personally only use the `runOnUiThread` method in my Instrumentation Tests. Since the test code does not execute in the UIThread, you need to use this method to run code that modifies the UI. So, I use it to inject click and key events into my application. I can then check the state of the application to make sure the correct things happened.

[For more info on testing and running code on the UIThread click here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html#RunOnUIThread)

Comment: Great explanation , specially link  for app  fundamentals its a must read for all beginners like  me  :)

Comment: Shouldn't you use an `AsyncTask` instead of `runOnUiThread` in most cases?

Comment: @JDJ the 2 techniques have different purposes: `AsyncTask` will get you OFF the main thread, into the background; `runOnUiThread()` will get you ONTO the main thread, from the background. So it depends what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 10):

If you execute blocking code (e.g. a Http-Request) in a separate Thread, consider using [AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example). Its `doInBackground`-Method runs on a separate Thread. `AsyncTask` provides you with methods `onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute` which are **guaranteed to run on the UI thread**.

If you need GUI-progress updates (e.g. via a progressbar) call `publishProgress` inside `doInBackground`. This leads to a subsequent call of `onPublishProgress` which is also **guaranteed to run on the UI thread**.

`onPostExecute` is automatically called after `doInBackground` returns.

Answer (score 5):

All UI drawings etc. happen in a separate thread. Its called the UIThread. If you want to make any change to UI u must use make sure it happens in UIThread's context. 
Easiest way of doing it is to make use of `runOnUiThread`

Comment: Can you prepare widget data structures (like inflate a Layout) in a non UI thread and then draw them later in a UI thread?

Comment: never tried that but technically it should be possible, since inflate just creates the data structure. Its the part when u attach is to an activity etc is when u need to do it in a UIThread context.