# Whats wrong with my Thread()-code?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I have a question regarding an Android application. I want to, later on, create a game and i am currently trying out classes and functions that I need to understand.
At the moment im trying to get a grip of how to use threads in a good way, but my application is "force closing" when i touch the button.

For this test application, all have on the screen is one TextView and one button.
The button is calling threadStart() when pressed. (onClick in xml)
And what i want it to do is to create a thread which increases the variable *value* by 1 and then report to the UI thread which then update the textview with the new value.

Can someone see what i am doing wrong with this small pice of code?

---

```
package com.weldeborn.tc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ThreadCounter extends Activity {

    TextView txtCounter1;

    int value=0;
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateResult();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        txtCounter1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter1);

    }

    protected void threadStart() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                doSomething();
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        value = value+1;
    }

    private void updateResult() {
        txtCounter1.setText(value);
    }
}
```

---

My code is based on an example from [Android Developer: The Common Tasks and how to do them](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html) section under the "Handling Expensive Operations in the UI Thread" heading.

I am thankful for any help.

Comment: Without LogCat error output you will never be able to debug your programs. Google it, use it. Also if you have XML code, you should use it.

Comment: but where is your onclickListener??????

Comment: In the buttonView (in the main.xml file) I use android:onClick="threadStart". I think what it does is to implement a onCliclListener, it has worked for my previous applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setText doesn't work correctly when you pass an integer, directly. Try converting it to String before:

txtCounter1.setText(String.valueOf(value));

Also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652560/android-ui-thread) about the usage of threads that need to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

if `threadStart` is your onClick the signature needs to be

```
public void threadStart(View v)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! I haven't manage to fix it yet but I will read the links suggested and also correct the int-String problem that i missed.