# Can I run Activity class methods from a java.util.TimerTask::run()?

Tags: android, timer

Inside my Android code, I'm responding to a button press by calling Timer.schedule(myTask,0,1000), which calls myTimerTask::run(), which is something like this:

nested within my Activity:

```
class mytimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //update my progress bar
        //if progress bar is full, i want to call a function that is in my activity
    }
}
```

Can I straight up reference one of my Activity methods from TimerTask?  It seems to crash the app when I try it.

Would it be better for me to handle my ProgressBar and eventual execution of code from a Runnable instead of a Timer/TimerTask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to yor code as follow. To know reason check following thread
[What is the Android UiThread (UI thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652560/what-is-the-android-uithread-ui-thread) or http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

```
   Timer t;
   Handler handler = new Handler();


t = new Timer();
Class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //update my progress bar
    //if progress bar is full, i want to call a function that is in my activity

                    }
           });
    }

    t.schedule(timeTask, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: So you're saying if I declare it like this as an actual TimerTask with a defined run(), it should work out instead of extending TimerTask like I am?

Comment: No don't want say that, I wan't to say that if you are trying to update UI of activity it should be done from UI thread.

Comment: Worked great!  Now I gotta figure out why calling MyTimerTask twice crashes the app, but the timer and firing of the function is perfect.  Thanks!