# How to set text of text view in another thread

Tags: android

I am tring to setText in another thread, that is, child thread. But for the following code, it is giving the error

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pb);
    this.tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.perc);
    tv.setText("30 %");
    pb.setProgress(30);
    pb.setMax(100);
}

public void set(int p)
{
    tv.setText(p + " %");
}

protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    pb.setProgress(20);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                int i = pb.getProgress();
                while(i <100)
                {
                    while(pb.getProgress()<100)
                    {
                        pb.incrementProgressBy(5);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                i+=10;
                pb.setProgress(i);
                Thread.interrupted();
                set(i);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Ravi,u can't directly update UI from thread use `Handlers` and `AsyncTask` and see this [Android Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask ](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Comment: U mean a different Thread to set Text which will use
handler.post(new Runnable(){
// 
});

Comment: you trying to set `TextView` value in Thread that's why u are getting this error

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need a reference to that textview and then do:

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(yourText);
    } 
});
```

in Kotlin:

```
val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
textView.post(Runnable { textView.setText(yourText) })
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I just want to know that this is creating new child thread of working in UI(parent thread).

Comment: @LoungeKatt There is only one UI-Thread. `View.post` uses the Handler, while `Context.runOnUiThread` checks, if the calling thread is the ui thread and posts to Handler, otherwise.

Comment: @LoungeKatt I had to giggle when I read that you think taking "separate UI thread" as something different than "separate reference" is "taking it too literally"

Comment: @Bondax Glad something made you laugh. It sounds like you take yourself entirely too seriously. If you need the whole thing explained using appropriate wording and clear examples, you should probably start a separate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558238/461982 To avoid confusion for later viewers: the key difference is that `runOnUiThread` may still cause an `android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException` while `post` will maintain the specific reference to the view being edited. Hopefully this wording is clear enough for you ;)

Comment: Tbis answer helped a lot I was getting lines of text in runnable, for read more /read less. Works fine in latest devices, but gave textview must not null on 21 api. I AM DOING  textview.Layout.Getlines

Answer (score 11):

Use `runOnUiThread` for updating the UI control. In your case:

```
runningActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tv.setText(p + " %");
    }
});
```

Edited:

```
Activity mActivity;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mActivity= this;
   ...
   ..//The rest of the code
} //close oncreate()

thread{
    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tv.setText(p + " %");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How to initialized Activity runningActivity.
Initializing it with null is giving run time error.

Comment: Thanks . This worked , Kindly suggest me which two use because both are working.
1) runningActivity.runOnUiThread
or
2) textView.post

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652560/what-is-the-android-uithread-ui-thread

Answer (score 2):

Either you can use `runOnUiThread` or use `Handler` to set text in TextView.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `handle` :

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(yourText);
    }
});
```

But your `textView` and `yourText` must be class fields.

In your thread (activity) where you create `textView` use:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

And pass `handler` into another thread.