# Updating time through implementation Runnable

Tags: java, android, time, runtime

I decided to ease the update time algorithm. Everywhere write an algorithm through the **Timer**. But if you implement **Runnable** the interface in the main activity, you can avoid creating an extra object.

I want it when I open the activation, the time was updated every second. But this does not happen. 
By the tag (ITTERATION) that I created, there is only one iteration.
Using an example from [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

[image: Screenshot of phone preview and logs]

I already broke my brain.
Help me please :(

```
package pac.twoproject;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {

    private static final String TAG = "ITTERATION";
    TextView tv;
    String time;

    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        //scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        time = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        tv.setText(time);
        Log.d(TAG, time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884246/ Try logging before you make the call to tv.setText. I suspect that an exception is thrown there

Comment: I do not get any exception. Or the log is not displayed or time is displayed again.

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService` suppresses exceptions. What's more, after one exception, the runnable is unscheduled by default. Wrap your run method body in an try-catch and log it yourself to see if that is what happens.

Comment: Я выталкивал каждую секунду. Сделал обертку исключения. Теперь метод Run выглядит так: `try {// мониторим код time = sdf.format (новая дата (System.currentTimeMillis ())); Log.d (TAG, время); tv.setText (время); } catch (RuntimeException e) {Log.d (TAG, "" + e); } Log.d (TAG, "1");` I get an exception 1 time.  **"android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."**  And how can I fix this? Links do? or how?

Comment: @worldsender Thank you, you helped me. I unsubscribed in fasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only modify `View`s from the main thread (GUI thread) of the application. In your case, when the `ScheduledExecutorService` calls `run`, it will do so in a different thread. The result is that `tv.setText(time);` throws a `CalledFromWrongThreadException`. The scheduler in turn, seeing that the `Runnable` threw an exception, will suppress future exections:

> [Documentation for ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)
>
> If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed

There is one, seemingly contradicting, thing left to explain: It works once. This is because your initial delay is `0`. This, in turn, means that the first execution might be run synchronously when calling `ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate`.

---

To fix this problem, you have to call `tv.setText(time)` from your main thread. How to do so, can be found in [this question](/q/9884246).

Answer (score 0):

The administrator helped **@WorldSEnder**! Thank you!
There was an exception *"android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"*. A new thread called by the function **scheduleAtFixedRate** could not update the text in the text field.
Solved the problem through **Handler**.

It was easier and more optimized to do it through Timer.
Or do you have any idea how to optimize it?

```java
package pac.twoproject;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {

    private static final String TAG = "ITTERATION";
    TextView tv;
    String time;
    Handler h;

    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        h = new Handler() { //создаем наш хендл, в котором пропишем получение из очереди сообщения и обновление нашей переменной
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Bundle bundle = msg.getData(); // достаем их сообщение наш бондаж
                String text = bundle.getString("key"); // из бондажа уже наше сообщение
                tv.setText(text);
            }
        };

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // функция которая запускает метод ран в новом потоке и повторяем его запуск каждую секунду
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try { // мониторим код
            time = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())); // считываем время
            Log.d(TAG, time); // пишем его лог

            Message msg = Message.obtain(); // создаем новое сообщение
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); // создаем новый сверток (бандаж)
            bundle.putString("key", time); // в него пихаем по ключу наше время (текст)
            msg.setData(bundle); // и уже бондаж запихиваем в сообщение
            h.sendMessage(msg); //отправляем сообщение
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, ""+ e);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not applied to android BUT ... `run()` is processing as it is...
**only once** except if you use:

```
while (true) {
    time = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    tv.setText(time);
    Log.d(TAG, time);
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. `ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate` is supposed to take care of repeated execution

Comment: I have a function (scheduleAtFixedRate) that makes the Run method every second. What for to me a cycle which will do it constantly.