# How to update Android Textview in an on going loop?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin. I have a loop that will continue going. But for some reason, I am unable to update the text view. Here is my simplified example.

```
var i = 0
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) {
    setString(i.toString())
    i++
    Log.i("Loging value of i === ", i.toString())
}


private fun setString (string : String) {
    tempText.text = string
}
```

Comment: is the log  showing the value ?

Comment: @ismailalaoui, the log is showing the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

What happened is because you are calling the UI updating inside a different `Thread` other than the main/UI `Thread`, your code can't reach the `View`s on the UI `Thread`.

Call the code that updates something on the UI inside a `runOnUiThread` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/11140429/10464730 (just copy the `runOnUiThread` part).

Or do a `.post` on the `TextView` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884344/10464730. Most of the time I use `runOnUiThread` first. If doesn't work, that's when I use `.post`.

Sorry the code I posted are `Java` but I think you could look up the equivalent of it on `Kotlin`.

Comment: I figured it out. Although setting the text must be done on the UIThread, so having a loop will block the UIThread. I used a Handler and Runnable instead of a loop and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, `loop` doesn't block the UI `Thread`. I think `.post` is what you'll need inside `loop`s. Well, `Handler` and `Runnable` would work as well. Glad to have been of some help.

Answer (score 1):

I also like this coroutines approach to update a textview, please drop it in your onCreate, also include your gradle implementation for coroutines:

```
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        var i = 0
        while (i < 100) {
            textViewId.setText("#$i")
            i++
            delay(300)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

View's can only be updated in UI Thread. try something like this :

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) {

 runOnUiThread(
            object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    //do your view update work here
                      setString(i.toString())
                }
            }
    )
    i++
}
```