# setContentView in a different thread

Tags: android

I am writing a server client on android platform. If one of the client send a message one of them, firstly message goes to server and server sends it to client. When a receiver client receive the message, i have to `setContentView` so I need to open messaging screen. But it takes the messages in a different thread and I pass as a reference my activity class.

```
Thread my = new MyThread(this);
```

and in the thread class ı cant set content view because give an error like `ViewRoot CalledFromWrongThread` what can I do?

Comment: Post your code so that we can help you modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // set contentview here
     }
});
```

Comment: But my thread is a different class and does a lot of things not just the set content. 
Thread threadReciever = new ThreadRecieve(this); threadReciever.start(); i create it this way. so what do you suggest?

Answer (score 7):

> The UIThread is the main thread of execution for your application.
>   This is where most of your application code is run. All of your
>   application components(Activities, Services, ContentProviders,
>   BroadcastReceivers) are created in this thread, and any system calls
>   to those applications are performed in this thread.
>
> When you explicitly spawn a new thread to do work in the background,
>   this code is not is not run on the UIThread. So what happens if the
>   this background thread needs to do something that changes the UI? This
>   is what the `runOnUiThread` is for. Actually you're supposed to use a
>   Handler (see the link below for more info on this); it provides these
>   background threads the ability to execute code that can modify the UI.
>   They do this by putting the UI-modifying code in a Runnable object and
>   passing it to the RunOnUiThread method.

(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653478/448625 for a more detailed explanation of what UI thread is)

In short, this should fix it:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // some code that needs to be ran in UI thread
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Thread threadReciever = new ThreadRecieve(this);
threadReciever.start();
this is my thread nad when ı got the message ı try to change contentview. So you advice me to use a runOnUiThread wright?

Comment: I recommend you to put `setContentView` line inside `run()` method in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

     }
});
```