# Run loop every second java

Tags: java, android

```
int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec. 
int period = 10000; // repeat every 10 sec. 
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
    { 
        public void run() 
        { 
            displayData();  // display the data
        } 
    }, delay, period);
```

And other:

```
while(needToDisplayData)
{
    displayData(); // display the data
    Thread.sleep(10000); // sleep for 10 seconds
}
```

Both of them doesn't work (application is force closed). What other options I can try?

Comment: mention the exception or log cat

Comment: please display the logcat error

Comment: You should do that in a background thread...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You code is failed because you perform sleep in background thread but display data must be performed in UI thread.

You have to run displayData from runOnUiThread(Runnable) or define handler and send message to it.

for example:

```
(new Thread(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (!Thread.interrupted())
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // start actions in UI thread
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                displayData(); // this action have to be in UI thread
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        // ooops
                    }
            }
        })).start(); // the while thread will start in BG thread
```

Comment: Could you explain everything a little bit? Your answer will be accepted, because it's working, but I want to understand it.

Comment: All UI changes have to be in main UI thread because background threads are async and can't perform changes in UI (and ui thread is sync and because of it if you start time consuming opertaion in this thread all buttons, view and other UI elements and even whole phone will be freezed, because system can't handle interface opertaions (click etc)). runOnUiTThread start body of this function in UI thread and from there you have to avoid heavy operations and only make changes and handle UI operations. check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652560/what-is-the-android-uithread-ui-thread

Comment: And you app crashed with exception like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi .

Comment: How do I stop this loop? @dilix

Comment: Is there a way to stop created thread in "displayData();" section? I tried using `Thread.interrupt();` but it wont compile saying "Non-static method 'interrupt()' cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: You can save you thread (new Thread at the first line) in variable and then interrupt it.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of knowledge. Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: for example finlal Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(...)); myThread.start(); and from you method you can call myThread.interrupt();

Answer (score 9):

Use `onPostDelayed()` accessed from any of your [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) or a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29). You save memory by not creating a `Timer` or new `Thread`.

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private final Runnable mUpdateUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        displayData();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUI, 1000); // 1 second
        }
    }
};

mHandler.post(mUpdateUI);
```

Comment: this approach is wrong I have tried this... it sometimes add values in large amount and sometimes it add in low in number

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@Override                    
    public void run() {   
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
            while(true){
               showTime(tv1);                                                                
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
               }catch (Exception e) {
                   tv1.setText(e.toString());
               }           
            } 
    }
```

U can also try this

There is an another way also that you can use to update the UI on specific time interval. Above two options are correct but depends on the situation you can use alternate ways to update the UI on specific time interval.

First declare one global varialbe for Handler to update the UI control from Thread, like below

Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Now create one Thread and use while loop to periodically perform the task using the sleep method of the thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Write your code here to update the UI.
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: If we want to use first part of your code in non-UI thread, it causes to exception. Because you try to change the text value of `TextView` that is belongs to `UI`. Please edit your code, and perform setText on UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

There several mistakes you have done:

1. You should never invoke Thread.sleep() on the main thread (and you should never block it for a long time as well). Once main thread is blocked for more then 5 seconds, an ANR (application not responding) happens and it is force closed.
2. You should avoid using Timer in android. Try Handler instead. Good thing about handler is that it is created on the main thread -> can access Views (unlike Timer, which is executed on its own thread, which cannot access Views).

   ```
   class MyActivity extends Activity {

       private static final int DISPLAY_DATA = 1;
       // this handler will receive a delayed message
       private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
           @Override
           void handleMessage(Message msg) {
               if (msg.what == DISPLAY_DATA) displayData();
           }
        };

        @Override
        void onCreate(Bundle b) {
            //this will post a message to the mHandler, which mHandler will get
            //after 5 seconds
            mHandler.postEmptyMessageDelayed(DISPLAY_DATA, 5000);
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread when i tried to get around the problem that you can't hide seconds in DigitalClock widget for Android. DigitalClock is deprecated now and the recommended widget to use now is TextClock. That don't work on old APIs tho... Therefore i had to write my own 24 hour clock. I don't know if this is a good implementation but it seems to work (and it is updated every second):

```
    import java.util.Calendar;

    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    /**
     * A 24 hour digital clock represented by a TextView
     * that can be updated each second. Reads the current
     * wall clock time.
     */
    public class DigitalClock24h {

            private TextView mClockTextView; // The textview representing the 24h clock
            private boolean mShouldRun = false; // If the Runnable should keep on running

            private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

            // This runnable will schedule itself to run at 1 second intervals
            // if mShouldRun is set true.
            private final Runnable mUpdateClock = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                            if(mShouldRun) {
                                    updateClockDisplay(); // Call the method to actually update the clock
                                    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateClock, 1000); // 1 second
                            }
                    }
            };


            /**
             * Creates a 24h Digital Clock given a TextView.
             * @param clockTextView
             */
            public DigitalClock24h(View clockTextView) {
                    mClockTextView = (TextView) clockTextView;
            }

            /**
             * Start updating the clock every second.
             * Don't forget to call stopUpdater() when you
             * don't need to update the clock anymore.
             */
            public void startUpdater() {
                    mShouldRun = true;
                    mHandler.post(mUpdateClock);
            }

            /**
             * Stop updating the clock.
             */
            public void stopUpdater() {
                    mShouldRun = false;
            }


            /**
             * Update the textview associated with this
             * digital clock.
             */
            private void updateClockDisplay() {

                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // 24 hour
                    int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 

                    String sHour;
                    String sMin;

                    if(hour < 10) {
                            sHour = "0" + hour;
                    } else sHour = "" + hour;

                    if(min < 10) {
                            sMin = "0" + min;
                    } else sMin = "" + min;

                    mClockTextView.setText(sHour + ":" + sMin);
            }

    }
```

Thankyou biegleux for pointing me in the, i suppose, correct direction!