# Run Countdown Timer in fragment and in background

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I am trying to run a countdown timer in a fragment. I have been able to achieve this but I can't seem to run it in background. How would I do this? Using a service requires onStart and onStop but these methods don't apply to fragments. What do I do?

Comment: look at this answer there should be few examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10032406/8187578

Comment: What I need is not there

Comment: The timer should run in the background even if the app is closed or destroyed

Answer (score 0):

In you need the countdown only when UI is visible you could use RxJava for example.

```
Disposable timer = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe(aLong -> {
                    // tick;
                });
```

Don't forget to `dispose` when timer is not use anymore

```
if (timer.isDisposed()) timer.dispose();
```

Or you can use `Observable.intervalRange(...)` to fire event specific number of times.

Or check this topic [Run loop every second java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687011/run-loop-every-second-java/11687210#11687210) to understand the `Thread` implementation in details.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question