# Understanding the UI thread

Tags: android, concurrency, android-asynctask, ui-thread

I am a beginner to `Android` and I have some confusions regarding `Android UI Thread`. Now, I know that no thread apart from the one that created the UI can modify it.

Great.
Here is the `Activity` from my first Android app which slightly confuses me.

```
public class NasaDailyImage extends Activity{
    public ProgressDialog modalDialog = null;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        //Instantiate progress dialog, skipping details.

        Button b = //get reference to button
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                modalDialog.show(); // show modal
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Getting feeds", 500).show();
                new AsyncRetriever().execute(new IotdHandler()); // Get the feeds !!
            }
        });
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public synchronized void resetDisplay(boolean parseErrorOccured, 
        boolean imageErrorOccured,
        IotdHandler newFeeds){
        if(parseErrorOccured || imageErrorOccured){
            // make a Toast
            // do not update display
        }else{
            // make a Toast
            // update display
            // based on new feed
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class AsyncRetriever extends AsyncTask<IotdHandler,Void,IotdHandler>{

        @Override
        protected IotdHandler doInBackground(IotdHandler... arg0) {
            IotdHandler handler = arg0[0];
            handler.processFeed(); // get the RSS feed data !
            return handler;
        }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(IotdHandler fromInBackground){
            resetDisplay( // call to update the display
            fromInBackground.errorOccured,
            fromInBackground.imageError,
            fromInBackground);
        }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


}
```

---

1. `onCreate` is on the UI thread so I can do whatever I want but `onClick` is not. **Why can I make a  `ProgressDialog` and a `Toast` in that method?** Why no error there?
2. The `AsyncTask` is subclass of the the `NasaDailyImage`. This means it can access **all** the methods of `NasaDailyImage` including `resetDisplay()` which updates the display. `resetDisplay()` is called in the `onPostExecute` which runs on a different thread from UI. So, why can I update the display there and yet get no errors ?

Comment: `onClick` and `onPostExecute` both run on the UI thread. The only thing in your code that doesn't is `doInBackground`, which as its name suggests, is run on a background thread.

Comment: @Geobits AFAIK, this is different from the old Java where the events were processed on a **different thread** right ? UI was one thread, the event processing was on the other

Comment: Read through this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653478/752320

Comment: In Android everything runs in the UI Thread unless you create a thread or use a framework class that uses threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `onClick()` is indeed on the UI thread. Most of what happens in an Activity happens on the UI thread.
2. `onPostExecte()` (and its counterpart `onPreExecute()`) runs on the UI thread as well. The [`AsyncTask.onPostExecte()` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) clearly states this. AsyncTask was deliberately designed such that developers could update the UI before and after they do background work.

In general, your code will be running on the UI thread unless you explicitly tell it otherwise. Once you create AsyncTasks, Runnables, or Threads, you need to ensure you understand where your code is executing. In an Activity, it is typically safe to assume you are on the UI thread.

Comment: AFAIK, this is different from the old Java where the events were processed on a different thread right ? UI was one thread, the event processing was on the other

Comment: What do you mean by "the old Java" and "events?" If you read through the source for Android, all the `onClick()` "event" is is a method in an interface. Events are nothing truly special.

Comment: I mean the `addActionListener` was processed on a different thread right ?

Comment: `ActionListener` is a part of the Java AWT package. AWT, Swing, and similar common UI-related packages found in most desktop Java apps do not exist in Android. I am not very familiar with `ActionListener` or it's methods of handling events, but it is not used in Android. There is no `addActionListener()` in Android.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are extending AsyncTask class , where async task class is calling its sequential method automatically. First `onPreExecute` then `doBackground` and finally `onPost`. If you want to change any ui change you can use `onProgressUpdate` method.
2. To use your activity class simple call `activityclass.this.resetDisplay()`. Because inner class scope sometimes failed to integrate except global varible.

Thanks