# Counter in loop

Tags: android

How to do sample counter in Activity? This is not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            updateTv();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateTv() {
        int counter = 100;
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        counter--;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no actual question here. At least state what's not working or what you're having problems with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `onCreate()` you're starting an infinite loop inside of the UI thread, blocking it completely. Alternatively you could use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for periodic updates. Maybe using a bigger delay and stop it sometime.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateTv();
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 17);
    }

    public void updateTv() {
        int counter = 100;
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        counter--;
    }
}
```

Anyway you should read [What is the Android UiThread (UI thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652560/what-is-the-android-uithread-ui-thread) for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) class which allows you to define a callback method that will be invoked at specified rate.

An example that fits your needs:

```
public class CounterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mCounterTextView;
    private Timer mTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);

        mCounterTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counterTextView);

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new CounterTask(100), 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
    }

    protected class CounterTask extends TimerTask {
        protected int mCounter;

        CounterTask(int initial) {
            mCounter = initial;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mCounterTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCounter));
                }
            });

            --mCounter;
        }
    }
}
```

One more thing that should be noticed. As `Timer` executes it's own thread - it prevents you from updating your UI from outside of the main thread. In that case
you have to register a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) method.

Also, calling `findViewById` in a loop is not the best idea.