# Fragment transition is not smooth as much as it should be

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, bottomnavigationview

i am using bottom navigation and fragments to display data in my app but after i started loading data in my app the animation of fragments transition started to stuck and overall performance of app looks ugly I don't know how this happened, without the data fragments transition works just fine.

here is how i am loading data and calling fragments.

> MainActivity.java

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_schedule:
                Fragment scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, scheduleFragment).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_teams:
                Fragment teamFragment = new TeamFragment();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, teamFragment).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_champions:
                Fragment championsFragment = new PointTableFragment();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, championsFragment).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_live:
                Fragment liveFragment = new LiveFragment();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, liveFragment).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_records:
                Fragment recordsFragment = new RecordsFragment();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, recordsFragment).commit();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

> Fragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team, null);
    lvTeam = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvTeam);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this.getContext());
    listTeam = db.displayTeam();


    adapterTeam = new CustomAdapterTeam(this.getContext(),listTeam);
    lvTeam.setAdapter(adapterTeam);
    adapterTeam.notifyDataSetChanged();


    return view;
}
```

can anyone explain what makes the transitions looks like having glitches, it kind of sticks while transition is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Fragment transition is not smooth as much as it should be

First thing is Fragment transaction is smooth but you are doing some long operation in UI thread so UI get stuck. And you feel that fragment UI is not smooth as i should be.

- I think your list have large amount of data which you are filling in once in [UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652560/what-is-the-android-uithread-ui-thread?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).  Instead of this you can use [paging](https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-tutorial-getting-started-recyclerview/) to load large data.
- `listTeam = db.displayTeam();`, other thing can be, may be you are fetching data from database in UI thread. If you do that in [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). You will overcome this issue.

or you can post delay your long operation, so that data load after fragment gets opened. (**Not recommended**)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team, null);
    lvTeam = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvTeam);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());
                    listTeam = db.displayTeam();
                    adapterTeam = new CustomAdapterTeam(getContext(),listTeam);
                    lvTeam.setAdapter(adapterTeam);
                    adapterTeam.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    },100);
    return view;
}
```

- Note that you can not do UI operation in `worker thread`.

**Edit**

Changed `this.getContext()` to only `getContext()`. Because this was referring to `Runnable`

Comment: hey thank you @Khemaraj but i am still having an error "can not resolve symbole this.getContext()". can you please help?

Comment: You were getting error because `this` keyword refers to current object. (in that case was `Runnable`). remove `this`.