# Run a method after onViewCreated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I have a fragment that creates a view, this view uses other classes and methods, but I want after create the view (inflated and initialized) is visible to the user call a method that is going to display the data usage per app.

Is there a way i can run a method after everything is inflated and initialized?

Thanks

Comment: Some code will be much more easier for us to help. `Is there a way i can run a method after everything is inflated and initialized?` Of course, you can run any method you like anywhere. But what is the real question here, what kind of `data usage` you want to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The view does not load until the method is over

That is because you are doing some long task in UI thread. Then even you put that method in `onResume()` or `onStart()`, your UI will freeze. You should use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) if you want do some long thread work after UI is inflated.

see

[What is the Android UiThread (UI thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3652560/6891563)

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

try running it into `onResume()`

It is the last called method of the fragment lifecycle

Comment: and what you got?

Comment: The view does not load until the method is over

Comment: but what view are talking about? the one you want to display after your main view is inflated? post your code please