# Why and when should I use a handler?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler

I recently saw an example of a stopwatch app , where the developer used a handler object to update the time displayed on a `TextView`. Why not use an ordinary loop that keeps on updating the text instead of using a handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every app has its own special thread that runs UI objects such as View objects; this thread is called the **[UI Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652560/what-is-the-android-uithread-ui-thread)**.

Considering your stopwatch example if you just add the loop inside your activity and keep the time going then it will **block** your UI thread and your app may become **unresponsive**. To overcome this problem and not to block the UI/Main thread we use separate threads to do such ongoing/long tasks.

So what he does is created a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) which will do the long running task and it sends the [update to UI thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui) to update textView when required.