# AsynTask showing UI element on doInBackground

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Why the modification of the graphical interface is performed in a seperate method (onPostExecute) and not executed by the background thread ?

Comment: The question is too broad. If you shared some of your research and stuck, meanwhile having this question, that'd be fine. However, SO is not the best place to ask such.

Comment: @TEHEMPRAH please take a look at the marked answer where my question is comprehend and well explained.

Comment: Please take a look at the mark above then, asking to clarify YOUR specific problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Interface is composed of [Views](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) and [ViewGroups](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup). These are created and manipulated in [UI thread aka Main Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652560/what-is-the-android-uithread-ui-thread). This is the only thread allowed to create and modify views. Ant attempt to do any UI related operation from a non-UI thread will throw an exception. AsyncTask have methods like `onPostExecute`, `onPreExecute`, `onProgressUpdate` to cater most common scenarios which arises with background processing.

I will try to explain the usecase with the simple example of Downloading a file using an async task.

**onPreExecute** - will be called before the background processing starts. So the progress bar for showing download progress can be made visible here. Then the `doInBackground()` will be invoked and download starts.

**onProgressUpdate** - This method is invoked whenever `publishProgress()` is called from `doInBackground()`. Since `doInBackground()` runs in different thread than UI thread, view cannot be updated to reflect the download progress. So `doInBackground()` will call `publishProgress()` with the progress of download. `publishProgress()` invokes `onProgressUpdate()` in UI thread and UI can be updated from here. `publishProgress()` can be called in a regular interval like 30 seconds or 1 minute to continuously update the progress

**onPostExecute** - Once the download is completed or the background task, `onPostExecute` will be invoked and this runs in UI thread. Here we can hide the progress and update UI to indicate download is complete.

Hope this clears why there is AsyncTask have those methods to update UI

Comment: great! thnx for the clarification kind sir.

Comment: Very nice explanation. A good teacher is in you ;-).

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for the appreciation. Upvotes inspire more to answer :-)