# webview not hitting server socket proxy

Tags: java, android, sockets, webview, serversocket

i have setup my webview's proxy using this snippet of code below:

```
ProxySettings.setProxy(mContext, "http://127.0.0.1", PORT);
```

Here is my socket server listener

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
thread = new Thread(runnable, this.getClass().getSimpleName());


public void startlistener() {
        listening = true;
        thread.start();

    }

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (listening) {
                try {
                    Socket accept = serverSocket.accept();

                    String data = getData(accept);

                    httpHandler.handleRequest(data);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

i have put a breakpoint on String data = getData(accept); and it never hits it

Below is the proxy class taken from https://gist.github.com/madeye/2297083

```
public class ProxySettings {

    private static final String TAG = "GAEProxy.ProxySettings";

    static final int PROXY_CHANGED = 193;

    private static Object getDeclaredField(Object obj, String name)
            throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object out = f.get(obj);
        // System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName() + "." + name + " = "+
        // out);
        return out;
    }

    public static Object getRequestQueue(Context ctx) throws Exception {
        Object ret = null;
        Class networkClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.Network");
        if (networkClass != null) {
            Object networkObj = invokeMethod(networkClass, "getInstance",
                    new Object[] { ctx }, Context.class);
            if (networkObj != null) {
                ret = getDeclaredField(networkObj, "mRequestQueue");
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private static Object invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName,
            Object[] params, Class... types) throws Exception {
        Object out = null;
        Class c = object instanceof Class ? (Class) object : object.getClass();
        if (types != null) {
            Method method = c.getMethod(methodName, types);
            out = method.invoke(object, params);
        } else {
            Method method = c.getMethod(methodName);
            out = method.invoke(object);
        }
        // System.out.println(object.getClass().getName() + "." + methodName +
        // "() = "+ out);
        return out;
    }

    public static void resetProxy(Context ctx) throws Exception {
        Object requestQueueObject = getRequestQueue(ctx);
        if (requestQueueObject != null) {
            setDeclaredField(requestQueueObject, "mProxyHost", null);
        }
    }

    private static void setDeclaredField(Object obj, String name, Object value)
            throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(obj, value);
    }

    /**
     * Override WebKit Proxy settings
     * 
     * @param ctx
     *            Android ApplicationContext
     * @param host
     * @param port
     * @return true if Proxy was successfully set
     */
    public static boolean setProxy(Context ctx, String host, int port) {
        boolean ret = false;
        setSystemProperties(host, port);

        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {

                Object requestQueueObject = getRequestQueue(ctx);
                if (requestQueueObject != null) {
                    // Create Proxy config object and set it into request Q
                    HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(host, port, "http");

                    setDeclaredField(requestQueueObject, "mProxyHost", httpHost);
                    ret = true;
                }

            } else {
                ret = setICSProxy(host, port);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error setting up webkit proxying", e);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private static boolean setICSProxy(String host, int port)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class webViewCoreClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewCore");
        Class proxyPropertiesClass = Class
                .forName("android.net.ProxyProperties");
        if (webViewCoreClass != null && proxyPropertiesClass != null) {
            Method m = webViewCoreClass.getDeclaredMethod("sendStaticMessage",
                    Integer.TYPE, Object.class);
            Constructor c = proxyPropertiesClass.getConstructor(String.class,
                    Integer.TYPE, String.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            c.setAccessible(true);
            Object properties = c.newInstance(host, port, null);
            m.invoke(null, PROXY_CHANGED, properties);
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    private static void setSystemProperties(String host, int port) {

        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port + "");

        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port + "");

    }
}
```

Am i missing something?

The ServerSocket runs in the same android app that the webview is running and the idea is to redirect all http requests to go through my socket server proxy.

Thanks

edit: i debugged the proxy code and it fails and throws this exception

```
07-01 15:44:02.894: E/GAEProxy.ProxySettings(11267): error setting up webkit proxying = java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

it happens when i call setProxy.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you: **Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**

You need to execute the code inside a Thread that implements Looper.

[Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989883/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare?lq=1)

[Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() inside AsyncTask for ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614663/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare-inside-a)

[Can't create handler inside thread which has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009816/android-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

Answer (score 0):

You can not set proxy programmatically if your application not signed with system signature. [How can you set the http proxy programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629644/how-can-you-set-the-http-proxy-programatically)

Comment: That is only if you want to set a proxy to the system worldwide but all i am doing here is setting it up for my own app 's webview

Comment: hi Jonney, where able to ever get this to work? I'm faced with the same issue.