# android error: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, dialog, handler, show, runtimeexception

I have an error from users of the android Market.
I have no idea when this error occurs .
The simulator and test phone runs the app perfectly!
Any1 any idea where to begin looking?
Thanks !

this is the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't
>   create handler inside thread that has
>   not called Looper.prepare() at
>   android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.(ViewRoot.java:259)
>   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
>   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>   at
>   android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:430)
>   at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
>   at
>   be.test.testerd$1.run(testscreen.java:103)

Comment: There have been a lot of discussion about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009816/android-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614663/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare-inside-as

Comment: You know a question is bad when the tags on the question provide more information about what might have caused the error than the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur, if you have used AsyncTask and in doBackground() method is not called on Main UI thread, and calling a Toast or anyother thing which runs on Main UI thread.