# How to show an alertDailogue in doInBackground(..) of an AsycncTask running..?

Tags: android

Error: `Getting error with UI thread..`
 when I'm trying to show an alert inside the doInBackground. Is there any posibility do this stuff?

```
private class LoggingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
                 //Get the sever connection and return the status

    if(status==0){
             // show an alert here....
    }
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: post the error log and code

Comment: Try Show dialog in onPostExecute() method. As doInBackground() run in Background tread, so you can't show dialog.

Comment: Its not possible to show alert in background.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5990202/1476699

Comment: why in doInBackground method? You can show that alert dialog in `onPostExeute()` method right?

Comment: @Abishek..I know the issue that in doInBackground we dont have the UI interaction.. I'm asking is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Get the sever connection and return the status

  publishProgress()
  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onProgressUpdate(values);
 //Do what ever you want 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do in background method doesnot allowed for UI changes,if you want to make any UI changes do in onpostexecute method

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Get the sever connection and return the status

        if (status == 0) {
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // show an alert here....

                }
            });

        }
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: @biraj.. you right but  if using Thread Handler ,the AsyncTask can be thrown out..

Comment: another solution is onPostExecute() given by @ Coderji

Comment: Already I followed tat way.. problem is tat ,if  this AsyncTask is in login functionality, status from server is Invalid Login, want to show alert from doInBack and exit the app..  your way is also good..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make a method that creates the dialog in your activty ( context would be the activity ) not in the AsyncTask. So when your

```
if ( status == 0 )
```

returns true, you call the method from the UI thread. In this way you are not creating the dialog in the AsyncTask and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**doInBackground() is not the right place to do the UI related Task**. You have to do it in onPostExecute. Or you can can start the dialog in **OnPreExecute()** and than cancel the dialog **onPostExecute().**

Answer (score 0):

Async tasks don't run on the ui thread that's why you can't do that. Store a boolean. Then call the alert dialog after the asynchronous task completes in the onpostexecute method.