# Passing data from asynctask to activity view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-activity, android-view

There are many Questions related to my problem  but none of them actually solved my problem. I tried almost all of them.

I'm trying to change values in layout after getting data from network source, but i'm getting nullpointerexception everytime.

Error I'm getting

```
03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832): java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at com.wishberg.app.CommunityPageActivity$SendRequest.onPostExecute(CommunityPageActivity.java:158)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at com.wishberg.app.CommunityPageActivity$SendRequest.onPostExecute(CommunityPageActivity.java:1)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    03-25 18:05:43.071: E/AndroidRuntime(4832):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my activity class

```
public class CommunityPageActivity extends Activity {

    public String wishid = null;
    private Context context = null;
    public String TAG = "communitypage";

    private String cachedName = "community";
    private static final int URL_LOADER = 0;
    private Menu optionsMenu;
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        wishid = i.getStringExtra("id");
        context = getApplicationContext();

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        Common.setRefreshActionButtonState(true, optionsMenu);

            progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Loading...");
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.show();

        setContentView(R.layout.community);
    }


    private class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        // http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-progress-bar-example.html

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        protected String doInBackground(String... requestURL) {

            String data = "";
            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;

            try {

                data = Common.readStream(in);

            } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException");
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
            } finally {
                if (null != httpUrlConnection)
                    httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return data;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString) {

            progress.dismiss();
            System.out.println(jsonString);
            JSONArray jsonArray = Common.getArrayFromJsonString(jsonString, 0);


            Inflater inflater;
//          View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.community);
            holder.txtWishName = (TextView) CommunityPageActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.tv_communitywishname);
            System.out.println(holder);
            System.out.println(jsonArray);
        }


        /* private view holder class */
        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView txtWishName;
            ImageButton btn_touchwood;
            ImageButton btn_addwish;
            TextView tvGesture;
            TextView tvNotes;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: O rly, tried everything? Try to init progress ...

Comment: I added few code which I had removed. in oncreate funtion.

Comment: set the progressbar appropiately.. You are not initiated the progressbar ,but you trying to dismiss that  [CKECK THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114344/how-to-show-an-alertdailogue-in-doinbackground-of-an-asycnctask-running)

Comment: I'm initializing it in oncreate funtion.  and I'm getting error on  `holder.txtWishName = (TextView) CommunityPageActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.tv_communitywishname);` line.

Comment: Of course you do, you did not initialize your `holder` variable, did you?

Comment: So now it might be a good idea to actually create the holder...

Comment: Not inside AsyncTask, at least. Check my answer

Comment: @Drew ViewHolder was an issue thanks

Comment: Check the updated answer, you're using `AsyncTask` wrong, man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not initialize your widgets inside an `AsyncTask`. Do not use inflater in there. You should initialize everything in `onCreate(..)` and alike.

Then you can perform expensive operations (HTTP connection and so on) in your AsyncTask. Then in `onPostExecute` you should update the UI widgets, which **are initialized** in your `Activity`/`Fragment`. At least that's how `AsyncTask` was meant to operate.

And as it was already mentioned, your `holder` variable is not initialized, that's why you get your Exception in the first place.

**Upd:** Moreover, parsing your JSON data in `onPostExecute()` is a bad idea, as it could negate the effect you would expect from usage of AsyncTask - this method is run on the UI-thread and could freeze it. Move the stuff to `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 2):

remove this line

```
 progress.dismiss();
```

you have not initialized and not used anywhere..
Based on comments

Your

```
ViewHolder holder is null
```

Comment: I added few code which I had removed. in oncreate funtion.

Comment: @m4k what is line 158??

Comment: holder.txtWishName = (TextView) CommunityPageActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.tv_communitywishname);

Comment: @m4k that too its not a listview why are you using ViewHolder in Activity??