# not able to make a call to POST from async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() inside AsyncTask for ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614663/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare-inside-as)

I am getting the following exception on making a call to a method, which eventually makes a  POST method call from my async task:

"Cant Create Handler Inside Thread That Has Not Called Looper Prepare in Android" .

I am using async task to show progress dialog.

Can you please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You should post your code as well otherwise how can we come to know where you did mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() inside AsyncTask for ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614663/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare-inside-as)

In short: the progress dialog's `show()` method must be called from the UI thread, not from the background thread. Use `onProgressUpdate` or `onPreExecute` for that.