# Camera Phonegap plugin

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I wrote an Android application using Phonegap. Now I need to use the camera but, since the Phonegap API for camera uses the Camera Intent, it provides me the camera with the native controls of my phone; instead I'd like to implement my own controls. To obtain that, I think I don't have to use the camera intent, instead I should use the long procedure (implement a framelayout, a CameraPreview, etc.), in order to draw my own controls. I can do that in a new application, but in the Phonegap plugin it doesn't work, since everytime I try to run the program, it shows the message "Failed because: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()". 
Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of SO answers that deal with this threading problem.

[Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

[Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() inside AsyncTask for ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614663/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare-inside-a)

[Can't create handler inside thread which has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009816/android-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

Comment: Hi Simon and thanks for your answer. I had already seen the links you posted, but since I'm a newbie with Android, I wasn't able to solve my issue, that's why I wrote this post. Now after many tests luckily I was able to solve it. Thanks

Comment: I used the method runOnUiThread, quite easy... now that I know it ;)
It is sufficient to call it and make all the changes to the program graphical interface inside it.