# Display toast message on android through jni call

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-x

I have followed [this](http://digitalsynapsesblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/cocos2d-x-launching-url-on-android.html) tutorial to launch a url on android through jni call. It runs successfully.
In the same way I want to display a toast message from my cocos2dx layer like this:

```
public static void openURL(String url) {
  Toast.makeText(me,url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But its crashing with error: `Can't create handler with thread`. Do you know how can I display it correctly?

Comment: maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614663/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare-inside-a) could help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code this will definately work for you.

- First Create one Runnable interface in your class file like this,

  ```
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {    

  @Override

  public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your url string...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }};
  ```
- Then create one Handler object and call that runnable interface like below,

  ```
  Create Handler object like,

  Handler handler;

  initialize it like,

  onCreate(){
      .................
      handler = new Handler();
      .................
  }

  then call runnable whenever you want like,

  handler.post(runnable);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run UI stuffs on a background thread.
You should use an AsyncTask and put that code in the on pre/post execute or if your just displaying a toast you can run it on the UI thread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this was from 2012.

I guess not a lot people use cocos2d-x. 
Ok this how you do this on cocos2d-x.

Edit the **AppActivity.java**

```
    public class AppActivity extends Cocos2dxActivity
    {
    private Activity activity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.activity = this;
        showToast();
    }

    public void showToast()
    {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello :D", 10).show();
            }
        });
    }

    }
```

This works very nice in cocos2d-x version 3.x
I test it. Of course JNI just will call the method and this must work.