# Handler constructor stops a thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

There's something weird happening. I can't show all the code, but situation is like this;

```
Runnable program = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        //This code is running
        new Handler();
        //This code not running
}};
new Thread(program).start();
```

Log shows nothing. Main thread is working good.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/12837289/1306419

Comment: and your problem is...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always declare `Handler` in UI thread.You need to provide the `Handler` with a `Looper` from some thread.E.g. from main UI thread:

```
 Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

`Handler` always runs in the `Looper` thread context. When you create another thread its context is different from the `Looper`. Right solution is to declare `Handlers` always in `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `Handler` needs a `Looper` polling on that thread first. By the way, there's usually no need to create a Handler *inside* non UI threads. Create a Handler outside the runnable. An easier alternative is to use `runOnUiThread()` method.